# Specify Azure Tools Version

Tags: .net, azure

How to specify Azure Tools version in ccproj files? For instance in my ccproj file, I have AzureSDKVersion to 2.5, how can I have it redirect to version 2.6 or 2.7 in the build server rather than using 2.5?

```
<AzureSDKVersion Condition ="'$(AzureSDKVersion)' == '' ">2.5</AzureSDKVersion>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' ">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\$(AzureSDKVersion)\</CloudExtensionsDir>
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click on .ccproj and go to properties. Under the Application tab, it should show you the current version. Like Microsoft Azure Tools Version: 2.5.

You will need this particular version installed on your 'build server' for it to build and deploy. You will not be able to add 'redirects'.

If your build server has an higher version, then you will have to upgrade your .ccproj to the higher version.